# Multiple binary logit regressions vs multinomial logit regressions?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution

Lets assume we have a dependent varible which can take on three values: 1, 2 and 3.

Is there any differences in running multiple binary logit regressions(ie. 1 vs 2 and 2 vs 3) or the multinomial logit regressions with 2 as the base group?
Will the results be the same as the base group is the same in both cases? I've tried to look it up but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: @starship: Please, when making edits, make sure to fix **al**l problems with the post and not just the "thanks"

Comment: Okay @kjetilbhalvorsen

Answer (score 1):

The regression coefficients are the same, but I believe the standard errors are not.  Using the full polytomous (multinomial) logistic model better exposes the true (large) number of parameters being estimated.